# Sketch the Graph $x = {(y + 4)^2} - 8$

Tags: calculus

My vertex for this parabola that opens towards the right is (4,8). Is that correct? This program is giving me a totally different graph. Am I wrong or is the program wrong? https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: Remembering that the square $(y+4)^2$ can have any non-negative value, what can you say about the smallest possible value of $(y+4)^2-8$.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: @user137452 What is the smallest non-negative number you know? What is 8 less than that number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to revise the transformations:

$x=\pm(y+a)^2+b$

- $+a \rightarrow $ shifts $a$ down
- $-a \rightarrow $ shifts $a$ up
- $+b \rightarrow $ shifts $b$ to right
- $-b \rightarrow $ shifts $b$ to left

In this particular example:

$x=(y+4)^2-8$ is just the parabola $x=y^2$ shifted 4 units down and 8 units to the left, so the vertex becomes $(-8,-4)$.

Comment: Thanks. I will utilize this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

As Jyrki stated, the minimum x value will occur when $$\left(y+4\right)^2$$ is minimized, or when $$y=-4$$

At this point, $$x=(-4+4)^2-8=0-8=-8$$

Thus, the vertex will be at (-8,-4).

Comment: So you utilized the substitution method. Thus I really can't just look at the equation and perform transformations?

Comment: See my post (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891449/sketch-the-graph-x-y-42-8/891485#891485).

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct: (4,8) is not the vertex of the parabola. If you move the constant term from the right to the left side and change to subtraction you get
$$x - - 8 = {(y -  - 4)^2}$$
This compares to 
$$x - a = c{(y -  b)^2}$$
where the vertex is $(a,b)$. We now see that the vertex is at $(-8, -4)$.

Answer (score 0):

I use calculus the find the relative extrema:
$$
x'(y) = 2(y + 4) = 0 \Rightarrow y = -4
$$

Because of $x''(y) = 2 > 0$ that is at least a local minimum at $y = -4$. So the shape is pretty clear.

Further $x(-4) = -8$, so the coordinates of your vertex point are $(y, x) = (-4, -8)$.

Please check the labels of your coordinate system, the usual plots are for $(x,y)$ pairs, $x$ on the horizontal, $y$ on the vertical axis. That way read the result as $(x,y) = (-8, -4)$.